# C# need help making sure multiple occurrences of the same letter are noted as a number

Tags: c#, string, button, textbox

I'm programming a periodic table for my school project in C#.
I want to make it so that if I press (for example) the H button 3 times it gets shown as H3. It now only works up to H2 and I have no idea why? Any help is welcome thanks in advance.

```
    private void btn_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_Chemical.Text = txt_Chemical.Text + "H";
        txt_Mass.Text = txt_Mass.Text + 1.006;
        int count = txt_Chemical.Text.TakeWhile(c => c == 'H').Count();
        if(count > 1)
        {
            txt_Chemical.Text = "H" + count;
            txt_Mass.Text = txt_Mass.Text + 1.006 * count;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no means now to verify if it is true now, but try:

I think it (working up to two H presses) might be due to this line in your code:

```
int count = txt_Chemical.Text.TakeWhile(c => c == 'H').Count();
```

Here is how TakeWhile works - it traverses the list from the beginning and stops at first occurrence that does not satisfy predicate. .

So when you do:

```
txt_Chemical.Text = "H" + count;
```

Your third letter becomes the value that count holds. So next time TakeWhile breaks on second element as "HH2".TakeWhile(c => c == 'H') yields two element collection.

**Try using separate variable to hold the state** (number of times that H has been clicked).

Additionally:

- use `var` instead of `int` before `count` - in case you change type later it will help
- if you care about precision - and for chemicals I assume you do, do not use double (1.006). Use decimals that guarantee precision (1.006m).

Comment: Thanks alot! Just using another variable solved the issue. Now that you told me I feel stupid for not coming up with it myself!